# OpenLDAP auditlog overlay module does not get loaded on Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ldap, openldap, debian-stretch

I use OpenLDAP on Debian Stretch. I wanted to use the `auditlog` overlay module, however it does not seem to load.

1. I added the module `auditlog` to my config

   ```
   # module{0}, config
   dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
   objectClass: olcModuleList
   cn: module{0}
   olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
   olcModuleLoad: {0}back_mdb
   olcModuleLoad: {1}memberof
   olcModuleLoad: {2}ppolicy
   olcModuleLoad: {3}pw-sha2
   olcModuleLoad: {4}refint
   olcModuleLoad: {5}auditlog
   ```
2. When I try to setup the overlay it throws a syntax error:

   ```
   adding new entry "olcOverlay=auditlog,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
   ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
       additional info: objectClass: value #3 invalid per syntax
   ```

That means that OpenLDAP does not recognize the `objectClass` `olcAuditLogConfig` which should have been added by the `auditlog` module. I tried using `auditlog.la` instead but that does not make any difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I always thought it is case sensitive. Can you show all your config and the modification ldif?

Comment: I updated my answer with a working solution on a fresh slapd install on Debian 9.4. If that does not work, it could have something to do with the module load order. In think the order matters sometimes, but I am not sure. The `auditlog.la` is the first module after `{0}back_mdb` in my production systems. Also try searching the subschema entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `olcAuditlogConfig`. At least this is what is defined in the schema, after adding the auditlog overlay:

```
# cat << EOF | ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: auditlog.la
EOF
```

and searching using the following command

```
# ldapsearch -QY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -b cn=subschema -s base + | grep -i olcauditlogconfig
```

which shows the schema entry for `olcAuditlogConfig`:

```
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.12.2.4.3.15.1
NAME 'olcAuditlogConfig'
DESC 'Auditlog configuration'
SUP olcOverlayConfig STRUCTURAL
MAY olcAuditlogFile )
```

Then create the logfile using correct permissions:

```
touch /var/log/auditlog.ldif
chown openldap:openldap /var/log/auditlog.ldif
```

And add the auditlog config:

```
# cat << EOF | ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://
dn: olcOverlay={0}auditlog,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
olcOverlay: {0}auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /var/log/auditlog.ldif
EOF
```

This results in the following `cn=config` on a fresh install of `slapd` (Debian 9.4 Stretch, slapd 2.4.44+dfsg-5+deb9u1):

```
# slapcat -n 0 -o ldif-wrap=no
...

dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}back_mdb
olcModuleLoad: {1}auditlog.la
structuralObjectClass: olcModuleList
...

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
...

dn: olcOverlay={0}auditlog,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
olcOverlay: {0}auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /var/log/auditlog.ldif
structuralObjectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
```

Comment: According to the man page it is `olcAuditLogConfig`. I tried both, none works.